# Uploading a csv into Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, upload, mime-types

Has anyone else had trouble uploading a csv file into Codeigniter? I'm getting a pretty annoying "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." error, even though I've quite explicitly set the upload type. Here's my code (should be fairly standard stuff):

```
    function doUpload() {

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'text/plain|text/csv|csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '5000';
    $config['file_name'] = 'upload' . time();

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    else {
        $file_info = $this->upload->data();
        $csvfilepath = "uploads/" . $file_info['file_name'];
        $this->addfromcsv($csvfilepath);

    }

}
```

I tried to cover all the bases in my allowed types - maybe I missed one?
Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: The **allowed_types** should be `$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';` and in **config/mimes.php** you should append `text/plain` in **csv** key. This is how i did it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unluckily there is no official specification, so there's quite a lot of them: the most popular among those that are missing are,

```
text/comma-separated-values|application/csv|application/excel|application/vnd.ms-excel|application/vnd.msexcel|text/anytext
```

It's highly unlikely you'll meet another one.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work after all. It seems so stupid that there isn't some way to set it to allow all file types. At least during development, even if they don't want to allow it in production.

Comment: @StormShadow: Actually there is a way, by extending the upload class. Here is the code, I used it in the past and works. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/123663/#757848 BTW, you might simply want to check out the particular mime type of your file and add that one instead.

Comment: I can find the mime-type of a file non-programmatically?

Comment: The subclass worked beautifully! Thanks! Big green check for you!

Comment: The CSVs that I was dealing with (downloaded from online banking) had a mime type of `text/plain` - just in case anyone else couldn't get it to work with the above ones.

Answer (score 32):

I got it working by adding [cbrandolino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546686/cbrandolino)'s suggested mimetypes to the config/mimes.php (great tip [jljohnstone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233552/jljohnstone)). So the csv property of my $mimes looks like this now:

```
'csv'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/anytext', 'text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel')
```

Comment: Very helpful. I`m wondering why the official CI did not include this. thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too. There is a list of CSV mime types in the `/appication/config/mime.php` file, but it's not as extensive as the one Jos posted.

Comment: I was missing two from the list, after adding them it got mine working!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem uploading .csv files. I solved it by determining the mime type by using `file -I file.csv` in the OS X Terminal. It reported that the mime type was 'text/plain' so I added that to the config/mimes.php file.

Answer (score 3):

-- Codeigniter **2.2.0** --

I did a quick debug on the ***Upload* library** and I have found out that sometimes the same source code running on different servers will identify the  same CSV file having different file type (i.e. *Server 1* identify the CSV file as: **application/vnd.ms-excel** but *Server 2* identify the same CSV file as: **text/x-c)**.

My fix was to add, in **application/config/mimes.php**, the file type that is identified by the server where was the issue. Hence, my csv array from **mimes.php** file looks like:
`'csv'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/anytext', 'text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/x-c')`.

Answer (score 2):

**first in allowed types just type 'csv'**

```
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

**second go to /config/mimes.php
and change the 'csv' array element as follows:**

```
 'csv' => array(
    'text/x-comma-separated-values',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/x-csv',
    'text/x-csv',
    'text/csv',
    'application/csv',
    'application/excel',
    'application/vnd.msexcel',
    'text/plain'
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things to upload csv file in codeigniter:-

i add mime type ( **application/vnd.ms-excel** ) to mime type file but the mean issue is codeigniter will only accept file name **userfile**. if you will set file name userfile then it works.

I think there might be another way but i unable to find that.