# Uploading svg file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload file with type svg in Codeigniter. But i could not do it with codeigniters built in upload library. I have tried to do it by adding this line in congig > mimes.php file

```
'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',
'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
```

but still no solution. I am getting this error -

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

here is my code

```
                    $dir = 'uploads/svg/';
                    $this->load->library('upload');

                    $config['file_name'] = $result . '.svg';
                    $config['upload_path'] = $dir;
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'image/svg+xml';

                    $this->load->library('upload');
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    $this->upload->do_upload();
```

Can anyone help me please?

thanks in advance

Comment: `But i could not do it`. Why? What error?

Comment: @Bibhas -- this is the error ----- The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: Specify that in the question. Plus show the code you're using to upload.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [CodeIgniter's File Uploading Class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)? See the `allowed_types` preference.

Comment: @ChrisL - yes i did. but can't find anything helpful for this situation. this is my first time to upload svg type file.

Comment: @rafi_ccj from what I see from documentation, the `allowed_type` option should be like this `$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';` Try putting `svg` there.

Comment: @rafi_ccj looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338258/1983684) to a similar question, providing that you have correctly added the SVG mime types to `mime.php` (which it appears you have done), all you need to do is pass `svg` as an allowed type, not the mime type itself.

Comment: @ChrisL - thanks! that was the wrong i was doing. many many thanks!

Comment: @Bibhas - thanks! i have done this and problem solved!

Comment: @rafi_ccj before running away, please accept an answer. That'll help people who face the same issues. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a list of allowed file extensions in `$config['allowed_types']`, separated by `|`, not MIME type. Try this -

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'svg';
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, check the mime type of your image [here](https://htmlstrip.com/mime-file-type-checker)

Then,
Open **mimes.php** from the config folder
then find the array element of index same as your image extension from the array,
add the mime type of your image to the array

In my case, I added 'image/svg':

```
'svg'   =>  array('image/svg+xml', 'application/xml', 'text/xml', 'image/svg')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'image/svg+xml';
```

This should be:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'svg';
```