# Uploading svg image with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, svg

I tried to upload svg files using CodeIgniter.

```
$config = array(
        'upload_path' => 'path',
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|svg|gif',
        'max_size' => 'size',
        'max_width' => 'width',
        'max_height' => 'height',
        'encrypt_name' => 'TRUE',
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('image_file')) {
        echo 'Success';
    } else {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
```

and i have read the same question in this link [Uploading svg file in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548964/uploading-svg-file-in-codeigniter) but codeigniter still does not allow the file type

Comment: What happens that you don't want to happen? What have you tried to do to fix it?

Comment: The php manual there are two mime type for svg namely svg and svgz.
and i will try to add to my config svgz

Comment: I just hit upon the same issue. Further debugging revealed that the mime type is being identified as text/plain for my svg by codeigniter. Since this is not present in in config/mimes.php under svg, it is failing in the mime_type check. I think the problem is with misidentifying the mime type for svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case php identified the file as image/svg

I just added to my **config/mimes.php**

```
'svg'   =>  array('image/svg+xml', 'application/xml', 'text/xml', 'image/svg'),
```