# Codeigniter Upload - File extension not allowed when uploading excel files on live server

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, xls, xlsx

I have allowed extensions gif/png/xls/xlsx. All of them work on local server. On live server only gif and png works no excel files.

I read about this bug in codeigniter 2.1.0 which was causing such behavior but I am using version 2.1.4. and as said it works on local server so I assume this should not be the causing problem.

That leaves me with the idea that my host account on godaddy does not allow excel uploads. But that also seems to be unreasonable to me. Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you checked the extension? Please check when you post the file and check. Also check the mime config file. If the extension not found in that file add there.
[something similar to this can found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731071/uploading-a-csv-into-codeigniter)

Comment: yep thanks for that...I guess not all of the following is necessary as it includes csv things but it made it work: 'xlsx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/anytext', 'text/plain', 'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel'),