# Codeigniter's file upload "allowed_types" option does not work properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, file-upload

```
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $file_config = array(
        'upload_path' => $dir,
        'allowed_types' => 'csv',
        'file_name' => strtoupper($this->input->post('class_name')) . '.csv',
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => 2048,
        'max_filename' => 128,
        'remove_spaces' => FALSE
    );
    $this->upload->initialize($file_config);
    // DEBUG
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file'))
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    else
        echo 'UPLOADED.';
```

For some reason, if I put `'allowed_types' => '*',`, it accepts it and it works just fine. but if I instead wanted only csv files: `'allowed_types' => 'csv',` and when I upload a csv file, it outputs an error: `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

How can I fix this without letting all types of files upload `*`, and instead only let `csv` files upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Codeigniter documentation says to use the files MIME type, the MIME type of CSV is "text/csv" so use that instead of just "csv".
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: still giving `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

Comment: Give this a try, there are many different types of csv MIME types and all are valid so you have to include them all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338258/1231563

Comment: Okay, I edited the line in the mimes.php file. and finally did `csv` for allowed_types, and it FINALLY worked. Thanks!