# How to set or upload only CSV type in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to import a CSV into MYSQL database. I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.sourcecodester.com/php/6477/how-import-csv-data-codeigniter.html)

Now i am getting an error that

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Below is my code for Controller :

```
function importcsv() {
    $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'text/x-comma-separated-values'|'text/comma-separated-values'|'application/octet-stream'| 'application/vnd.ms-excel'|'application/x-csv'|'text/x-csv'|'text/csv'|'application/csv'|'application/excel'|'application/vnd.msexcel'|'text/plain';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(
                    'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
                    'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
                    'phone'=>$row['phone'],
                    'email'=>$row['email'],
                );
                $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'csv');
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
        } else 
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        }

    } 

    public function chk_attachment() // callback validation for check the attachment extension
    {
        $file_type = array('.csv');
        if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']))
        {
            $ext = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'],"."));
            if(in_array($ext,$ext_array))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('chk_attachment','Attachment allowed only csv');
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
           $this->form_validation->set_message('chk_attachment','image field is required');
                return false;
        }
    }
```

The call back function was suggested by a user on stackoverflow who had same issue solved, but somehow didn't work for me. I have a users table and i just want to insert users using the uploaded CSV but somehow its not allowing me to upload a CSV.

**This is the Library**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 


    /**
     * CodeIgniter CSV Import Class
     *
     * This library will help import a CSV file into
     * an associative array.
     * 
     * This library treats the first row of a CSV file
     * as a column header row.
     * 
     *
     * @package         CodeIgniter
     * @subpackage      Libraries
     * @category        Libraries
     * @author          Brad Stinson
     */

    class Csvimport {

        private $filepath = "";
        private $handle = "";
        private $column_headers = "";

       /**
         * Function that parses a CSV file and returns results
         * as an array.
         *
         * @access  public
         * @param   filepath        string  Location of the CSV file
         * @param   column_headers  array   Alternate values that will be used for array keys instead of first line of CSV
         * @param   detect_line_endings  boolean  When true sets the php INI settings to allow script to detect line endings. Needed for CSV files created on Macs.
         * @return  array
         */
        public function get_array($filepath='', $column_headers='', $detect_line_endings=FALSE)
        {
            // If true, auto detect row endings
            if($detect_line_endings){
                ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", TRUE);
            }

            // If file exists, set filepath
            if(file_exists($filepath))
            {
                $this->_set_filepath($filepath);
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;            
            }

            // If column headers provided, set them
            $this->_set_column_headers($column_headers);

            // Open the CSV for reading
            $this->_get_handle();

            $row = 0;

            while (($data = fgetcsv($this->handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {   
                // If first row, parse for column_headers
                if($row == 0)
                {
                    // If column_headers already provided, use them
                    if($this->column_headers)
                    {
                        foreach ($this->column_headers as $key => $value)
                        {
                            $column_headers[$key] = trim($value);
                        }
                    }
                    else // Parse first row for column_headers to use
                    {
                        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
                        {
                            $column_headers[$key] = trim($value);
                        }                
                    }          
                }
                else
                {
                    $new_row = $row - 1; // needed so that the returned array starts at 0 instead of 1
                    foreach($column_headers as $key => $value) // assumes there are as many columns as their are title columns
                    {
                        $result[$new_row][$value] = trim($data[$key]);
                    }
                }
                $row++;
            }

            $this->_close_csv();

            return $result;
        }

       /**
         * Sets the filepath of a given CSV file
         *
         * @access  private
         * @param   filepath    string  Location of the CSV file
         * @return  void
         */
        private function _set_filepath($filepath)
        {
            $this->filepath = $filepath;
        }

       /**
         * Sets the alternate column headers that will be used when creating the array
         *
         * @access  private
         * @param   column_headers  array   Alternate column_headers that will be used instead of first line of CSV
         * @return  void
         */
        private function _set_column_headers($column_headers='')
        {
            if(is_array($column_headers) && !empty($column_headers))
            {
                $this->column_headers = $column_headers;
            }
        }

       /**
         * Opens the CSV file for parsing
         *
         * @access  private
         * @return  void
         */
        private function _get_handle()
        {
            $this->handle = fopen($this->filepath, "r");
        }

       /**
         * Closes the CSV file when complete
         *
         * @access  private
         * @return  array
         */
        private function _close_csv()
        {
            fclose($this->handle);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731071/uploading-a-csv-into-codeigniter

Comment: New file uploading user guide location here http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: @Saty  i tried that but same error i think there is something wrong other than that part of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv'; to your $config array.

for more help check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Also go through the file on path application\config\mimes.php for more clear understanding about csv array support on file upload type

You can update this array if you really want...

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel')
```

Comment: Hi, i had kept this but no good it always show an error maybe i have something wrong with other part of code

Comment: Check file details by using Print_r($_FILES); check whethr the file type belongs to csv array.

Comment: where should i be doing this??

Comment: First replace '|'  to | in your initialized $config['allowed_types']

Comment: Use print_r after statement $this->load->library('upload', $config);

Comment: $config['allowed_types'] = 'text/comma-separated-values|application/csv|application/excel|application/vnd.ms-excel|application/vnd.msexcel|text/anytext';

Comment: question code updated see i have added the library code as well

Comment: just REPLACE 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'text/comma-separated-values|application/csv|application/excel|application/vnd.m‌​s-excel|application/vnd.msexcel|text/anytext';   BY  STATEMENT $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89874/discussion-between-rajan-and-mangesh-sathe-ind).