# How do I Importing CSV Data to mysql using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to add a feature on my application on which the admin can bulk upload users on the database using a CSV file and then stores it to the database. I am currently using codeigniter as my PHP framework. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731071/uploading-a-csv-into-codeigniter 

check this link

Comment: Build a form in which you can upload files, validate the file, save the uploaded file on the server, load the file into the database. Explaining every step would be too much for one question I feel

Comment: hi Hardik, thanks for that link. however, i want to insert the data from the CSV to mysql. I found that link to be just uploading csv files to a folder